# hidden mod rewrite to sub folder only for certain paths

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Im looking for some advice to deal with a less than standard rewrite setup i need to create using apache.

a client i have has a custom cms for there site, but they also have wordpress multisite setup on the domain root where only wp-admin is visible.

The multisites are sub domained which isnt a problem. the folder structure looks like this:

/
index.php << custom cms entry
...
wordpress/ << root of wordpress install
  wp-admin/
  wp-includes/
  index.php
  .htaccess

on the root domain IF the url contains (wp-*|my-account) i want to rewrite this to the folder "wordpress" without the url being effected.

It would also be great if the .htaccess inside the wordpress install would continue to work as normal to.

Ive tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wp-includes/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^my-account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wp-signup.php
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

And ive also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/?my-account/(.*)$ wordpress/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?wp-admin/(.*)$ wordpress/wp-admin/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?wp-includes/(.*)$ wordpress/wp-includes/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?wp-login.php wordpress/wp-login.php [L,NC]
```

I cant seem to get any of them working (both variations on answers ive found on here) and im pretty sure its down to my knowledge than something that isnt possible. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested at all, but it should work:

```
# Pass any url beginning with wp- or my-account to wordpress
RewriteRule ^(wp-.*|my-account/?$) wordpress/$0
```

In the wordpress `.htaccess` you'll have to change `RewriteBase /`  to `RewriteBase /wordpress/`.

However, if your permalinks don't match this rule, they will be broken.